# Cant receive an array by form POST method in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having this problem where I just can't receive my data as an array

HTML: I'm sending it via Form inside a bootstrap modal like this

```
                 <div class="lines">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control"  
                      name="txtqtd[]" id="inputPassword2">
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Thats my JS where I append multiple inputs with the same name

```
                     $(function () {
                      $(".addDiv").click(function () {
                        novoDiv = $("div.lines:first").clone();
                        novoDiv.find("input").val("");
                        novoDiv.insertAfter("div.lines:last");
                        var esvaziaproduto = document.getElementsByName('txtqtd[]');
                      });
                    });
```

And thats how I get my data in php

```
$p_item = $_POST['txtqtd'];
$counter = count($p_item);
```

It just receives the first value of the array

Comment: Variable $counter prints only 0 does not matter how many inputs where created in html

Comment: try error_log( print_r($_POST, 1)); to see what your post object consists of. Judging by your above form input, there is only going to be one value for - $_POST['txtqtd'];

Comment: This *should* not matter when sending/receiving data to/from PHP, but you should not clone a DOM element with an `id` attribute without changing it in the process. In other words, any ID needs to be unique.

Comment: Also please show your whole form. Is it submitted "naturally" or via JS in any way?

Comment: @Jeto it's submitted naturraly via post

Comment: @Jeto I changed the id, now it has just name

Comment: If you check your browser's Network tab (F12 on most browsers), can you see all the values being passed or just the first one?

Comment: @Jeto just the first value, problably my js is not working quite right

Answer (score 0):

Does your JS actually send all the values and is it PHP that only receives the first one or does the JS only send 1 value? (You can check in your console/network tab)

If it's the first option:

What kind of POST do you execute (JSON, form-encoded,..)?

The incoming data for your PHP script could probably be like `txtqtd=1,2,3,4`, so your `$_POST['txtqtd'] = "1,2,3,4"`, which results in a count of `1`. Try `var_dump()` the result to make sure.

Then you'll probably need to explode the `txtqtd` value like `$pieces = explode(',', $_POST['txtqtd])` which would then result into `pieces -> (4)[1,2,3,4]` with a count of `4`.

Comment: Actually javascript it's not sending all data

Comment: If I type in 123, 321 and something it will return just === txtqtd[]: 123

Answer (score 0):

They are two solutions namely:

Solution 1. If posting by ajax

`$.ajax({
            url: yoururl,
            type: $(this).attr("method"), //put method='post' in form
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: new FormData(this), //This will post every field in form as is
            processData: false,
        })`

so at your server you will be able to access

```
$_POST['txtqtd']; as array
```

Solution 2. If you want to first access the values from with in Javacript just use a simple method below

```
var $p_item = $("input[name='txtqtd[]']")
          .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
console.log($p_item);
```

Will give a JavaScript array

Comment: can u help me with ajax? I 've never used it

Comment: `$(function () {
                      $(".addDiv").click(function () {
                        $.ajax({
            url: yoururl,
            type: $(this).attr("method"), //put method='post' in form
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: new FormData(this), //This will post every field in form as is
            processData: false,
        });
                      });
                    });`

Comment: use the above method. Don't forget to put method post in the form. As well as your one URL which has the p_item = $_POST['txtqtd']; part